# Setting an Azure Worker Process to run functions async

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asynchronous

I have a fairly simple Azure Worker Process application with a main thread that calls a number of functions.

Each function basically grabs some data via an API call to an external site, manipulates the data, then pushes it somewhere else via an API call.  Each function calls a different external site.

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Entry point called", "Information");

        while (true)
        {
            Function1();
            Function2();
            // etc etc, there are nearly a hundred functions

        }

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);

    }
}
```

I have no experience in using the Async properties, and very little with Azure itself.  Each function takes an hour or so to run, so my 100 functions take 100 hours.  How can I change the function to run async?  Is it all within .NET, or do I need to programatically spin up additional Azure processes and call different functions to them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The worker role is your application entry point, the interface between your code and the host code. The `Run` method is how Azure gives you a thread to run your application code. If you need to run lots of work in parallel, you can use normal .NET threading techniques to do so:

- Create a new [`System.Threading.Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to run each task on. Good for long-running operations where you will not yield the thread.
- Create tasks using [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have them scheduled for execution on the Thread Pool. Good if you have short-running tasks, or tasks which regularly yield the thread.

Unless you have 100 cores available, trying to make 100 tasks execute simultaneously will cause a lot of thread-switching overhead and may result in substantially slower performance than you could reach if you were to queue up the activities to work over a smaller number of thread.

---

If you say you have 100 things which take 1 hour each, are they all doing CPU-central activities for that full hour? If, like most applications, they're spending most of their time making requests of other resources and waiting for results, you should try and take advantage of Asynchronous programming techniques, like using `Task` with `async` and `await` to yield the thread often.

Yielding a thread is the best way to increase your system throughput - it's able to do other work whilst you wait for the task to complete. Your CPU cores are kept busy and all the work can proceed more quickly.

Comment: Thank you for this - in my example I'm mostly waiting for results, so the Task with async and await sounds like the way to go, but I don't know how to do this - can you point me to a relevant example ?

Comment: Generic examples should be easy to find if you just search for "C# async await". If you update your question with details of what you're actually doing, a specific example could be provided.